# How to compare fields from databases with variable name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to return a field 'CreditAdvisor_PrimaryCode' from a database 'DWH_Staging' where a field 'CooperationEndDate' from the database 'DWH_Staging' does not matvh a field 'DatumUkonceni' from a database with variable name. We have a procedure 'adm.MaxBatch' returning actual name of the database with variable name.
I've tried:

```
DECLARE @db_is nvarchar(50)

SELECT @db_is = mb.DatabaseName
FROM adm.MaxBatch mb    
WHERE mb.SourceID = 1

PRINT @db_is

SELECT
    ca.CreditAdvisorCode_Primary
FROM 
    @db_is.CS_Prodejci prod 
    JOIN DWH_Staging.dim.CreditAdvisor ca 
        ON prod.KodOZ = ca.CreditAdvisorId
WHERE
    prod.KonecCinnosti <> ca.CooperationEndDateId
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what did you find? There are obvious issues with this code, but I am curious what effort you have tried.

Comment: @clifton_h Multi-part identifier could not bound. But I don't know how to work around.

Comment: The issue is at compile time. There are no variable databases/schema/table names. Instead, like the answer below, use dynamic sql. My suggestion is to read: [Dynamic SQL | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql) before you expose yourself to `SQL Injection`

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while selecting a database from variable you need to make Dynamic for Eg:

```
DECLARE @db_is nvarchar(50),@string NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @string='  Select   ca.CreditAdvisorCode_Primary 
               from '+@db_is+'..CS_Prodejci 
               JOIN DWH_Staging.dim.CreditAdvisor ca 
               ON prod.KodOZ = ca.CreditAdvisorId
               WHERE prod.KonecCinnosti <> ca.CooperationEndDateId '

  PRINT @string
  EXEC(@string)
```

Comment: What is the variable @strt?

Comment: that's print wrongly I had Removed it.@strt has nothing to do with query

Comment: check your Join Condition

Comment: Tip: It's a good idea to use [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) around the variable elements within an object name.